# Difference in years of array of Timestamp with today

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have an array of timestamps of size 500 as follows:

```
>>>TimeStampArray[0]
Timestamp('2017-02-20 14:00:19')
```

I want to find time difference of each element of that array with today's date and represent this output in days.

e.g. TimeStampArray[0] - today()  = 3 days

I have tried using pandas datetimeindex with TimeStampArray but it keeps failing to convert to a format which I can then apply timedelta function to.

Edit:

```
type(TimeStampArray.dtypes)
<type 'numpy.dtype'>
```

head() give `error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'head'`

I just printed entire array and the contents look as:

```
   '2010-12-21T22:00:10.000000000', '2014-11-02T00:00:17.000000000',
   '2014-07-14T15:00:11.000000000', '2010-12-31T12:00:18.000000000',
   '2010-12-20T00:00:33.000000000', '2010-12-20T00:00:33.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: Can you post an output of `print(TimeStampArray.head()); print(TimeStampArray.dtypes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `TimeStampArray` seems to be a NumPy array - IMO it's much easier to work with Pandas series:

```
In [178]: TimeStampArray
Out[178]:
array(['2010-12-21T22:00:10.000000000', '2014-11-02T00:00:17.000000000', '2014-07-14T15:00:11.000000000', '2010-12-31T12:00:18.000000000', '
2010-12-20T00:00:33.000000000',
       '2010-12-20T00:00:33.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

In [179]: (pd.datetime.now() - pd.Series(TimeStampArray)).dt.days
Out[179]:
0    2256
1     845
2     956
3    2247
4    2258
5    2258
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I also agree pandas is better way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `abs` with [`TimedeltaIndex.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.days.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=10).values
print (rng)
['2015-02-24T00:00:00.000000000' '2015-02-25T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2015-02-26T00:00:00.000000000' '2015-02-27T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2015-02-28T00:00:00.000000000' '2015-03-01T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2015-03-02T00:00:00.000000000' '2015-03-03T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2015-03-04T00:00:00.000000000' '2015-03-05T00:00:00.000000000']

today = pd.datetime.now()
print (today)
2017-02-24 22:09:25.162455

print (abs(pd.DatetimeIndex(rng) - today).days)
[731 730 729 728 727 726 725 724 723 722]
```

Comment: This gives error as: TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')

Comment: You might not need the "round". Look MarkU syntax. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, obviously there can be more possible solutions, now my solution is simplier too.